# How to perform row wise if and mathematical operations in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Input Data:

```
Period   Invoice_No   Amount      Date
Mar-19    123         5000.00     12-02-2019
Mar-19    124         5000.00     13-02-2019
Mar-19    125         7000.00     13-02-2019
Mar-19    126         5000.00     19-02-2019
Mar-19    127         5000.00     25-02-2019
Mar-19    128         5000.00     27-02-2019
```

So basically want to check if first row amount (5000.00) is equal to second row amount; then perform a date difference function (13-02-2019 "-" 12-02-2019) and if difference is less than "5 days" then the following is the output. If difference is more than 5 days exclude from the output (Line number 4)

```
Period   Invoice_No   Amount      Date
Mar-19    123         5000.00     12-02-2019
Mar-19    124         5000.00     13-02-2019
Mar-19    127         5000.00     25-02-2019
Mar-19    128         5000.00     27-02-2019
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Have a look at "shift" https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html and post the code you wrote trying to solve the problem.

Comment: Hello, .shift will only add a coloumn and shift the dates up/down; but how to use if in pandas?

Comment: ok, maybe i missunderstood. row 1 is kept because it match the conditions with row 3? or is it kept because it belongs to row 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shift the date to calculate the time delta between the rows. After I filter for the conditions you defined.

```
df['Date_diff'] = df['Date'].shift(-1)
df['Date_diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(x['Date_diff'] - x['Date']),axis=1)

mask = (df['Amount'] == df['Amount'].shift(-1)) & (df['Date_diff'] < pd.Timedelta('5 days'))
mask2 = (df['Amount'] == df['Amount'].shift(1)) & (df['Date_diff'].shift(1) < pd.Timedelta('5 days'))

print(df[mask | mask2].drop('Date_diff', axis=1))

   Period  Invoice_No  Amount       Date
0  Feb-19         123  5000.0 2019-02-12
1  Feb-19         123  5000.0 2019-02-13
```

Comment: Tried using this; but still it does not fully satisfy the condition:

Comment: It also gave me other rows where difference was not "0"

Answer (score 0):

IICU:

```
df.sort_values(by=['Period','Date'], inplace=True)#Sortby Date
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['days']=df['Date'].diff().dt.days#Find days difference
df['Amountdiff']=df['Amount'].diff()#Find amount difference
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)#Fill any NaN/NaT
df2=df[df.Amountdiff==0]
df2.iloc[:,:4:]
```

Outcome

[image]

Comment: What the error and on what version of pandas are you. I have tried it onto different machines and it works.

Comment: @Pratik, its is unfair for you to edit output after answers have been posted without warning and claim the code is not working. Thats not how you seek help

Comment: @wwne: I am really sorry! I used the code and realized that there was an inherent error in the input data earlier mentioned. I am sorry that I did not mention that I have changed the input and output

Comment: The issue mainly is that when I perform the code, it works and filters most of the rows; but still there are rows which should not come.

Comment: Is there any code which works similar to the "if" formula in excel; so that I can first check the amount in row0 with row1 and if that is "0" then check the difference.

Comment: see edit and if ok, click on the rows on the left to accept answer